# Invalid object name 'dbo.AspNetUsers' in Asp.NET MVC 5 Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

If you have an existing database, and you want to include ASP.NET Identity tables to it, you can face this error. You may not know how to integrate **[AspNetRoles], [AspNetUserClaims], [AspNetUsers], [AspNetUserLogins]** tables into your existing database when you start. Although there are a lot of resources about this topic, this answer tries to be short and to the point. You may want to use the Database-First approach in Entity Framework together with the ASP.NET Identity feature of ASP.NET MVC. This is a very short tutorial for dummies. I am sorry if my English is poor.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is the shortest integration of Asp.NET Identity tables to your existing database.

1) Open new project or your existing project in Visual Studio (2015 or 2013). Open your **Server Explorer** and open your **DefaultConnection**.Find your Identity tables. (In WebConfig file, localDB connectionstring should be active. And your other existing Database's connection string should not be active.) Double Click your **[AspNetRoles], [AspNetUserClaims], [AspNetUsers], [AspNetUserLogins]** tables. And copy all of their SQL codes.

2) Open your existing database in your SQL Server Management Studio, right click your database and click **New Query** past here what you copied in 1st part. You will past something like that:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetRoles] (
[Id]   NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
[Name] NVARCHAR (256) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetRoles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);


GO
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [RoleNameIndex]
ON [dbo].[AspNetRoles]([Name] ASC);



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers] (
[Id]                   NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
[Email]                NVARCHAR (256) NULL,
[EmailConfirmed]       BIT            NOT NULL,
[PasswordHash]         NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[SecurityStamp]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[PhoneNumber]          NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[PhoneNumberConfirmed] BIT            NOT NULL,
[TwoFactorEnabled]     BIT            NOT NULL,
[LockoutEndDateUtc]    DATETIME       NULL,
[LockoutEnabled]       BIT            NOT NULL,
[AccessFailedCount]    INT            NOT NULL,
[UserName]             NVARCHAR (256) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);


GO
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UserNameIndex]
ON [dbo].[AspNetUsers]([UserName] ASC);


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] (
[UserId] NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
[RoleId] NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC, [RoleId] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles_dbo.AspNetRoles_RoleId] FOREIGN KEY ([RoleId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetRoles] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
 );


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_UserId]
ON [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]([UserId] ASC);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_RoleId]
ON [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]([RoleId] ASC);



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins] (
[LoginProvider] NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
[ProviderKey]   NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
[UserId]        NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUserLogins] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([LoginProvider] ASC, [ProviderKey] ASC, [UserId] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserLogins_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_UserId]
ON [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins]([UserId] ASC);



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims] (
[Id]         INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[UserId]     NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
[ClaimType]  NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[ClaimValue] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUserClaims] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserClaims_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_UserId]
ON [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims]([UserId] ASC);
```

If you forget the lines which starting with GO, you will exactly see the error which is in Title of this question. Run this query and wait for succesfully creation of tables. Your existing database is now ready for Identity features of  Asp.NET MVC 5.

3) Open WebConfig in your Visual Studio. We will change connectionstring here. Write this:

```
 <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=YOUR_SERVER_NAME;Initial Catalog=YOUR_DATABASE_NAME;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=YOUR_USER_ID;Password=YOUR_PASSWORD.;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Instead of localDB connection string. Which is this:

```
 <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-....mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-...;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

That's all you need to do. Run your project and Register. You can see your new user data in AspNetUsers table, in your existing database.

Comment: Hi @Alparslan , there is another way to do this. Change the connection string like what you did in section 3. Then do a register user on the webpage. You will see the 5 tables being created.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I saw your solution in some questions here. But this did not work in my situation. Or maybe I did something wrong. I got some errors. Instead of researching these errors on the internet, and If some people face with those errors, they can use this solution.

Comment: You saved my life. I have, for some reason, 2 DBContext classes (IdentityContext & Custom Context).
I dropped my db when the custom context changed. Identity Context did not recreate the tables. Meh

Answer (score 7):

I have faced same problem, Here I was forget to call **EnsureCreated()**.
After calling this method it will create all tables required by Identity.

**Startup.cs**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
        ...

        // Make sure we have the database
        serviceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>().Database.EnsureCreated();
}
```

Comment: This only applies when you have `Data -> Migrations` in your solution. If you've removed the migrations files like I have, this will do nothing.

Answer (score 5):

In Visual Studio go to "Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console" and in console window (inside Visual Studio) execute "Update-Database" command

Comment: This is not quite correct. Per this article [link](https://blogs.msmvps.com/marafa/2014/06/13/how-to-create-asp-net-mvc-authentication-tables-in-an-existing-database/) I had to issue 3 commands in PS : Enable-Migrations
Add-Migration Init
Update-Database

Comment: blazer SqlException: Invalid object name 'AspNetUsers'...

The 00000000000000_CreateIdentitySchema.cs code did not execute.
No identity tables were created in my db until I issued this command from the Package manager Console:

    Update-Database

Of course, first the correct connection string needed to be set in appsettings.json

Answer (score 3):

I go through same issue.
sometime user create customize class for membership hence asp.net dont create `AspNetUsers` table
example :

```
public class Member : IdentityUser
{
    Public int MemberID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Family { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

}
```

in this scenario ASP.NET create `Member` table and when user want to authenticate,ASP.NET search for `AspNetUsers` and did not find this table.
this problem solved with add TableAttribute in begin of customized class

```
[Table("AspNetUsers")]
public class Member : IdentityUser
{
    Public int MemberID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Family { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Similar to above you could do this in ConfigureServices**

```
services.Configure<ApplicationDbContext>(o =>
{
  // Make sure the identity database is created
  o.Database.Migrate();
});
    //     Applies any pending migrations for the context to the database. Will create the
    //     database if it does not already exist.
    //     Note that this API is mutually exclusive with DbContext.Database.EnsureCreated().
    //     EnsureCreated does not use migrations to create the database and therefore the
    //     database that is created cannot be later updated using migrations.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps I took to add `AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFramework` to an existing project with an existing SQL database. Same as OP, I was missing the required database tables in order to use the framework. I'm running ASP.NET Core v6.0.5.

1. With Visual Studio, create a new temporary project using the `ASP.NET Core Web App (Model-View-Controller)` template. Choose authentication type `Individual Accounts`.
2. Open the `Package Management Console` (you can find it under *View -> Other Windows -> Package Management Console*).
3. In the *Package Management Console*, you can initialize the missing database tables by typing `Update-Database -Connection 'CON_STR'` where `CON_STR` is your database connection string. The `Package Management Console` will create the tables. It will also print the SQL queries it used to create them.

After the SQL tables had been created, I had no further issues.
Here is the code from my *Program.cs* file:

```cs
builder.Services.AddDbContext<IdentityDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(CON_STR));
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove folder /.vs/[solution_name]/DesignTimeBuild.
Next from command line: dotnet ef database update --context [your_db_context_name]
It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to package manager console,

copy paste this line -->
Add-Migration Init   -->
press enter

copy paste this line -->
Update-Database   -->
press enter

Answer (score -3):

the fastest way is to recreate a new project and select the authentication to individual. And then use the old files to instead the new ones.