# Database definition for Identity User - dbo.AspNetUsers and dbo.Users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am porting an existing webapp that used Membership to a new app that uses Identity. I have updated all table definitions, created a new MVC 5 web application in VS Community Edition 2015, version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3, then brought in code from the old project, as well as some code I had tried in a project from Adam Freeman's book.

[But UserManager etc seem to want both dbo.Users and dbo.AspNetUsers.](http://www.ismlab.usf.edu/aspnetusers.png)

How do I initialize the Identity ApplicationDBContext so that UserManager, SignInManager etc can read from the database? Any assistance would be great.

Currently, when the Users table is named "Users", I get the following error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Invalid object name 'dbo.AspNetUsers'.
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.AspNetUsers'.

Line 150:           User tempUser = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
```

And when the table is named "AspNetUsers" as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41995546/1385857), I get the error:

```
Invalid object name 'dbo.Users'.
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.Users'.
```

For reference, the Identity objects are not changed from the template definitions:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("IdentityEFContext", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        ApplicationUserManager manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
        ...
    }

public class ApplicationUser : User
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

The conventional EF code works, e.g.

```
private IdentityEFContext dbContext
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<IdentityEFContext>();
        }
    }

List<Activity> Activities = dbContext.Activities.ToList();
List<User> Users = dbContext.Users.ToList();
```

The context definitions outside Identity are standard EF code first:

```
public class IdentityEFContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public IdentityEFContext() : base("IdentityEFContext") { }

    //public DbSet<UserLogin> UserLogins { get; set; }
    //public DbSet<UserClaim> UserClaims { get; set; }
    //public DbSet<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
    //public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    //public DbSet<User> AppUsers { get; set; }
    ...    
}
```

The table name for users is defined using Fluent

```
public class UserConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserConfig()
    {
        ToTable("AspNetUsers");
        HasKey(u => u.Id);
        ...
    }
}
```

Wonder if this is relevant. I tried the following, and applicationDBContext only contains roles and users. This should provide all the needed information, but thought I would report.

```
ApplicationDbContext db1 = context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>(); // contains ROLES And USERS
IdentityEFContext db2 = context.Get<IdentityEFContext>();       // contains all tables for all defined dbsets
```

Comment: Your `public class ApplicationUser : User` should be actually `public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried, but then statements such as `Models.User CurrentUser = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(currentUserId);` in the rest of the application throw errors that `ApplicationUser cannot be implicitly converted to type User` Also, my User class is indeed `public class User : IdentityUser {}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UserModel**

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<User> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

**ApplicationDbContext**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("IdentityEFContext", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .ToTable("User");
    }
}
```

**ApplicationUserManager**

```
public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
{
    ApplicationUserManager manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<User>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, in the end, this is exactly what I did, though since I already had a definition for User in my Entity Framework model, I moved the pre-defined method as a static method, commented out the ApplicationUser definition in IdentityModels and replaced all references to ApplicationUser to User

Comment: Thanks, did not realize about accepting the correct answer