# How do I resolve my Invalid object name 'dbo.AspNetUsers' error?

Tags: c#

I changed my connection string when starting a new mvc project because I needed to use some info out of an existing database. Now I get a "Invalid object name 'dbo.AspNetUsers' when I try to load the startup page. A [quick google search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040976/invalid-object-name-dbo-aspnetusers-in-asp-net-mvc-5-entity-framework) says the issue happens because you are connecting to an existing database using asp.net users. Still, this should not occur since I am not using code first migrations, right? What is more, I am using Active Directory to authenticate my users instead of individual user accounts.

In addition, the `AspNetUsers`table does not exist in the database I am calling in the web.config:[image]

Comment: You are getting this error because you don't have that table, not in spite of. You will need to provide more info to get exact reason why is this happening.

Comment: I will try adding it once I get to the house and test it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to the fact that I am not using the UserStore or the ApplicationUser provided by the Individual User Accounts defaults I needed to change this:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
```

to

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
```

Optionally If you are using Code First Migrations you could add the initial migrations, remove all of the sql code from the up and down methods, and finally update the database. Even though the tables will still not exist it seems to satisfy the compiler and your project as the error goes away and the page loads as expected.