# Why my identity database table is not migrated to Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core-mvc

When publishing my first ASP.NET Core 2.1 web app in Azure from Visual Studio 2017, I am setting up EF migrations like in the picture below:

[image: PICTURE]

After running `Publish`, the identity table is not created. In Configure -> Settings I have info, that `No databases found in the project`.

Also I am using console command:

```
dotnet ef database update --context AppIdentityDbContext
```

What gives me same result. Connection strings I am taking from Azure `Show database connection strings`, updateting them with username and password.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Everything works perfectly on my computer. I will be thankful for any suggestions to check.

Right now, after trying to populate Identity table:
public static class IdentitySeedData

```
 {
        private const string adminUser = "****";
        private const string adminPassword = "****";
        public static async Task EnsurePopulated(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
        {
            IdentityUser user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(adminUser);
            if (user == null)
            {
                user = new IdentityUser("Admin");
                await userManager.CreateAsync(user, adminPassword);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting error:

```
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Invalid object name 'AspNetUsers'.)

System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(bool includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
SqlException: Invalid object name 'AspNetUsers'.

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__108_0(Task<SqlDataReader> result)
```

**UPDATE**: I found out, that my problem occurs only identity database.

Comment: Do you have a database to put the tables in? (Informational message says "No databases found in the project".) Also, you might not be able to use "Admin" as a username in Azure SQL.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' yes, I was trying to seed empty table with Admin's login and password. I am still learning Azure, and I managed to find tables for other bases, but only identity base is not migrated.

Comment: As I did not managed to migrate my Identity database to Azure, I found alternative solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040976/invalid-object-name-dbo-aspnetusers-in-asp-net-mvc-5-entity-framework Anyway, thanks for effort guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I did not managed to migrate my Identity database to Azure, I found alternative solution here: [Invalid object name 'dbo.AspNetUsers' in Asp.NET MVC 5 Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040976/invalid-object-name-dbo-aspnetusers-in-asp-net-mvc-5-entity-framework)